# textarea issue in phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I have a textarea with some heigh and width. I use it to enter one or more email IDs. When I enter IDs by typing, the text gets wrapped. When I am integrating my app with phonegap , and then enter the IDs through phone's address book, the text is not getting wrapped.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi! Could you provide some code?